# Move Images from Gallery to Server in android

Tags: android, image-gallery, image-uploading

I have an Application in android for capturing Images and then saving them To Emualtor gallery Fine.But I have to Move all photos in gallery to server when i capture them from phone they should automatically be uploaded to server and deleted from gallery i.e want to move the images to server.Please tell me how can i Pick the all images from gallery and then move them to server.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the Camera

```
String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1234);
```

Processing the Image

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1234) {
String filepath = getPathfromUri(mCapturedImageURI);
//Now you have the file path. upload it to server.
//uploadtoserver(filepath);
//Now delete it after uploading 
new File(filepath).delete();
}
}
```

Method to convert Uri to actual path

```
public String getPathfromUri(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String path= cursor.getString(column_index);
cursor.close();
return path;
}
```

Comment: Sir What will do this code ? Will this work for me as I require in My question